# Grails unit tests: Accessing defined beans via grailsApplication

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have some (non-Grails-artifact) classes that access the service layer beans via passing around the *grailsApplication* object. However I'm having trouble unit testing the classes implemented in this way. Why doesn't the bean get registered in the main context?

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class ExampleTests {
  void setUp() {}

  void tearDown() {}

  void testSomething() {
    defineBeans {
      myService(MyService)
    }

    assert grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("myService") != null
  }
}
```

The above code fails with:

**org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myService' is defined**

What I'm trying to do is access services from plain old Java classes via the grailsApplication. This works, but not in unit test environment. Should I do it differently?

```
class POJO {
  MyService myService;

  public POJO(GrailsApplication grailsApplication) {
    myService = (MyService) grailsApplication.getMainContext().getBean("myService");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is that in the `GrailsUnitTestMixin` the applicationContext that holds your beans is set as the `parentContext` in the `grailsApplication`

```
beans.registerBeans(applicationContext)

static void initGrailsApplication() {
...
//the setApplicationContext in DefaultGrailsApplication set's the parentContext
grailsApplication.applicationContext = applicationContext
}
```

So you can get your beans with:

```
defineBeans {
  myService(MyService)
}

assert applicationContext.getBean("myService")
assert grailsApplication.parentContext.getBean("myService")
```

**EDIT**

Today I faced the same problem, and my solution is:

```
@Before
void setup() {
  Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.registerMockBean("myService", new MyService())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I edited my question with an example of how I'm trying to get the beans in my Java classes. This works in normal environment, but not in unit test. Should I search for the required bean in the parentContext instead of mainContext, or both? Can you point me to more information about parentContext vs. mainContext?

Comment: Good question. I replicated this in the grails mailing list, let's see what they can add. In some codes that I wrote I'm using mainContext too, probably find this is some example, but in this case I'm always using integration tests.

Comment: I found [in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#theUnderpinningsOfGrails) the difference between the parentContext and the mainContext, and still waiting to confirm, but I thing that your unit test should work, so maybe is a bug from Grails.

Comment: What you can do in this cases is mock the way you get your service, though the groovy metaClass, instead of getting this fixed in your constructor. Or declare your class as a spring bean, allowing dependency injection.

Comment: Hi, see my edit. I needed this today and become with a solution.

Comment: As of at least grails 2.4.4, this solution doesn't work.  For that version I needed to use registerSingleton instead of registerMockBean, as answered by Ed OConnor-Giles.

Comment: @SérgioMichels Hi, which Grails version did you use? Because it seems to not work in 2.3.11. I get `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsWebApplicationContext.registerMockBean() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, com.me.services.MyService)`

Comment: @EelLee Sorry but this is an old answer. I don't remember which version I was using.

Comment: I need to register datasource bean, so using the same approach:
`def dataSource
Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.registerMockBean("dataSource", dataSource) ` gives error since dataSource is not a class.
Can you please help me with this, about how to register dataSource in applicationContext.

Answer (score 7):

In my case (grails 2.4.4) the accepted solution didn't work but pointed me in the right direction, this line worked instead as the bean factory in the mainContext within my unit test was an [OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.html)

```
Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.beanFactory.registerSingleton('myBean', new MyBeanClass())
```

Comment: tested with grails 2.5.1 and working (the accepted solution must be for an earlier version of grails and didn't work). Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me either.

Answer (score 2):

I have spent some time with the same issue, in my case running grails 2.2.4 and having (in src/groovy):

```
import grails.util.Holders
class SomeClass {
  transient myService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean 'myService'
  .....
}
```

Which is a bit different to question author, but at least it will be useful for someone coming from search engine results

Nevertheless accepted answer did not work for me, so I came up with a bit different approach of mocking and registering service used in SomeClass.

```
import grails.util.Holders
.. other imports
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class SomeClassTests {
    @Before
    void setUp() {
        Holders.grailsApplication = grailsApplication
        defineBeans {
            myService(MyServiceMock)
        }
    }
    ....
}

class MyServiceMock extends MyService {
  // overriden methods here
}
```