# how to inject TagLib MockObjects in Grails Controller Unit test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, taglib

```
i have tagLib like this:
```

static namespace = 'j2'

```
  def brandMessage = { attrs, body ->   
    def brand = ConfigurationHolder.config.j2.brand
    def messageCode = (brand ? brand+".":"") + attrs.code    
    def defaultCode = attrs.default ?: attrs.code
    out << message(code:messageCode,      default:message(code:attrs.code,default:defaultCode))
  }
```

and using in :

```
public static def translate = {code,Object[] args->
      def dflt = (args.size()>0?args[0]:"");
        def taglib = ApplicationHolder.application?.getMainContext()?.getBean("com.j2.taglib.BrandMessageTagLib")
        def translatedValue = taglib?.brandMessage(code:code,default:dflt)?:""

        return translatedValue
      }
```

in controller we are using :

```
flash.message = I18nUtils.translate('admin.groups.delete.success')
```

while running the app its working fine. But when we are creating the Unit test case for the controller it throwing the error message like this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.j2.taglib.BrandMessageTagLib' is defined
```

but i defined this in the Test class like this:

```
defineBeans {
                myService(BrandMessageTagLib)
            }
            def beanName=applicationContext.getBean("myService")

            log.info("beanName->"+beanName)

            def mockMyTagLib = mockFor(BrandMessageTagLib)
            mockMyTagLib.demand.brandMessage(1) {code, defaultMessage ->
                def defCode = new MarkupBuilder(new StringWriter())
                defCode.applyTemplate('<j2:brandMessage code="admin.groups.delete.success"')
            }
            controller.brandMessageTagLib = mockMyTagLib.createMock()
```

Even this is also same errormessage throwing.

anybody have idea is a greate helpfull.

Thanks 
arnagendla

Comment: Same thing related [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532417/grails-unit-tests-accessing-defined-beans-via-grailsapplication/13533461#13533461), basically Grails define beans in the parentContext, so you will need to mock the way you get your tagLib.

Comment: Thanks Michels. When i used these i got the bean name like beanName:com.j2.taglib.BrandMessageTagLib@48b9e55c and parentBean:com.j2.taglib.BrandMessageTagLib@48b9e55c, But the bean is not injecting into the Controller in the case of Unit test. any idea?

Comment: What about create getter and setter for your bean?

Comment: There is no setter and getter methods for the bean. it's a TagLib. we are using in get the i18n message properties. Even if we use debug it is out of line below: **flash.message = I18nUtils.translate('admin.groups.delete.success')** from controller..